# Vb.net Function Return list from the Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

I am Creating a Function which have to return me the list of the Student so I can show it on my html page

Model

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

tell me how to write the current function to return

```
Public Function FillList() As IList(Of Student)
    Dim Obj as IList(Of Student) = new IList(Of Student)
    Dim Obj_Student As Student = new Student

    Obj_Student.Name = "Zeor"
    Obj.Add(Obj_Student)

    Obj_Student.Name = "One"
    Obj.Add(Obj_Student)

    return Obj_Student
End Function
```

But I am getting Error

```
<asp:Repeater id="cdcatalog" runat="server" SelectMethod ="FillList" ItemType="WebApplication16.Student">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <td><%# Item.Name %></td>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    <p>Your app description page.</p>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Can we send models to Aspx Web Form

And Other Question is how to send a Model, from Aspx to Html and can I use For each in that with html as we do in MVC by using   I am new in Web Form...

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim obj As List(Of Student)  = New List(Of Student)

  Dim Su As New Student

        Su.Name ="aaa" 
        obj.Add(Su)
          Su.Name ="aaaaa"
obj.Add(Su)
```

Answer (score 0):

FillList cannot do this:

```
Dim Obj as IList( of Student) = NEW IList( of Student)
```

It has to use List in the New constructor:

```
Dim Obj as IList( of Student) = NEW List( of Student)
```